# Applying regex to uri variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, regex, json

I have the following ajax function that is returning three images(PORTRAIT, SQUARE and LANDSCAPE) from a JSON response:

```
$.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                "Authorization": bearerToken
            },
        }).then(function (response) {
            var obj = response;
            $("#imageid").css("border-color", "#ccc");
            $(".search-results").empty();
            for (var property in obj.entity.entries) {
                if (obj.entity.entries.hasOwnProperty(property)) {

                        var imageURI = obj.entity.entries[property].uri + "&" + imageCacheBust;
                        $(".search-results").append($("<li><a href='" + imageURI + "' target='_blank'><div class='thumbnail'><img width='30' height='30' src='" + imageURI + "' target='_blank'/></img><div class='caption'><p>" + obj.entity.entries[property].orientation + "</p></div></a></li>"));
                    }
                }

        }).fail(function (data) {
            $(".search-results").empty();
            $(".search-results").append("<p class='alert alert-danger'>Invalid ID</p>");
            $("#imageid").css("border-color", "red");
        });
```

The LANDSCAPE and SQUARE images are returned in a URI formatted like this: 
`http://xx.domain.com/api/v2/img/55527b6060b27c50d1def7b6?location=LANDSCAPE&1`
`http://xx.domain.com/api/v2/img/55527b6060b27c50d1def7b6?location=SQUARE&1`

The PORTRAIT image is returned as:
`http://xx.domain.com/api/v2/img/5550fdfe60b27c50d1def72d&43`

I am using a regex to chop off everything after the **LAST** `d` at the end for the portrait, as it is not using cacheing (as the others are). However, this is not working correctly, and the image is not showing up.

Comment: In portrait mode there is nothing after `d`

Comment: Put wrong url up and edited.

Comment: It seems the code is only appending for NON Portrait images and doing nothing for portrait ones. Is this intentional ?

Comment: You want to delete after which `\d`.There are 3 `d` there

Comment: @Ankit, I am trying to append all three images.

Comment: you could try to split on the `&` and take the first returned element, but that would only wok if you only had the single `1`

Comment: In that case you might need to move `$(".search-results").append(...` outside the if-else. (or have it inside both)

Comment: You can't say "chop after 'd', when I think what you really want is to extract the last path part before ? or &.

Comment: Also, why is there a '&' in the last url? I don't think that's proper URL formatting.

Comment: @JamesWilkins, I need to keep everything in the uri, EXCEPT for whats after the last d.

Comment: @JamesWilkins, the `&` is to add extra characters for cache busting

Comment: @Matt: Query strings are used to bust caches and begin with `?`. if you just put an `&` without the `?`, you'll get a 404. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/?foo=bar) vs [this](http://stackoverflow.com/&foo=bar).

Comment: The title of this question is misleading. It should have been "How do I append a query string parameter?"

Comment: Exactly, use `?`, not `&`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution by taking part of @Ankit idea and appending the images to both `if` and `else` statements, and changing the `&` in the first one to `?`:

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            "Authorization": bearerToken
        },
    }).then(function (response) {
        var obj = response;
        $("#imageid").css("border-color", "#ccc");
        $(".search-results").empty();
        for (var property in obj.entity.entries) {
            if (obj.entity.entries.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                if(obj.entity.entries[property].orientation == 'PORTRAIT'){
                    var imageURI = obj.entity.entries[property].uri + "?" + imageCacheBust;
                    $(".search-results").append($("<li><a href='" + imageURI + "' target='_blank'><div class='thumbnail'><img width='30' height='30' src='" + imageURI + "' target='_blank'/></img><div class='caption'><p>" + obj.entity.entries[property].orientation + "</p></div></a></li>"));
                }else {
                    var imageURI = obj.entity.entries[property].uri + "&" + imageCacheBust;
                    $(".search-results").append($("<li><a href='" + imageURI + "' target='_blank'><div class='thumbnail'><img width='30' height='30' src='" + imageURI + "' target='_blank'/></img><div class='caption'><p>" + obj.entity.entries[property].orientation + "</p></div></a></li>"));
                }
            }
        }
    }).fail(function (data) {
        $(".search-results").empty();
        $(".search-results").append("<p class='alert alert-danger'>Invalid ID</p>");
        $("#imageid").css("border-color", "red");
    });
```

Comment: Simply testing the query string would seem a more robust and condensed solution, e.g.,  url += (url.indexOf('?')>=0 ? '&' : '?') + 'buster=' + (new Date()).getTime();

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `split` instead?  If I am reading your issue correctly, you should be able to replace this:

```
var regex = /[^d\/]*$/;
var imageURI = regex.exec(obj.entity.entries[property].uri);
```

. . . with this . . .

```
var imageURI = obj.entity.entries[property].uri.split("&")[0];
```

That would split the `uri` value into an array containing "http://xx.domain.com/api/v2/img/5550fdfe60b27c50d1def72d" and "43" and then you would just reference the first part with the `0` index (which, I believe, is what you are looking for).

Answer (score 0):

```
d[^d/]*$
```

Use this.Replace by `d`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/mT0iE7/12

Comment: The problem with that, is that I need to keep the last `d`, as its part of the URI.

Comment: @Matt you have to replace by `d`.So the last `d` will be der.See demo.